# Access the main controller's scope from inside a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Suppose the following blueprint code:

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="...">
        <div ng-repeat="...">
            <div ng-repeat="...">
                <div ng=if="..." my-directive>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>    

myApp.directive('myDirective',  function() {
    return {                   
        controller: function($scope){
            console.log('controller scope');
            console.log($scope);
        },  
        link:function(scope,element){ 
            console.log('link scope');
            console.log(scope);    
        }
    }
});
```

Both outputs in console will point to the scope created by `ng-if` directive. My question is **how may I access myCtrl's scope from inside the directive** . Of course not by using $parent.$parent....

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way could be by using `require` in the directive, like:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <div my-directive></div>
</div>


var myApp = angular.module("app", []);

myApp.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope) {
    this.text = "I am in Controller Scope";
    this.getValue = function() { return this.text; };
});

myApp.directive("myDirective", function() {
    return {
        require: "^ngController",
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngCtrl) {
            elem.text(ngCtrl.getValue());
        }
    };
});
```

**EDIT**

In your case, I think you could use the controller scope variables and methods in the directive by using scope binding with `&`; snippet below:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl as vm">
    <my-directive on-get-value="vm.getValue()">
    </my-directive>
 </div>

angular.module('app', [])
.controller('MyCtrl', function($window) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.getValue = function() { $window.alert("I am in Controller Scope"); };
})
.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
       onGetValue:'&'
    },
    controllerAs:'vm',
    controller: function($scope) {
         $scope.onGetValue();
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Yes you are right. However, I forgot to mention (my blueprint was not accurate) that I am using ui-routing. Therefore, there is no ng-controller. The whole page is bound to myCtrl via ui-routing. Any idea for that case? Thank you

Comment: @ILIAS, I updated my answer and added a scope binding with the directive. I hope that will solve it. Let me know about it..

Answer (score 0):

Use services to share data between angular components. This question might be a good start: [Share data between AngularJS controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919962/share-data-between-angularjs-controllers). This approach will work for sharing data between controller and directive as well

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating your directive, the returning function is called DDO (Directive Defining Object). One of its attributes is 'scope'. if you initialize it with scope : true, the directive will prototypically inherit the parent scope. If you set scope: false, the directive will use the parent scope. And finally, if you set scope : {...}, it will created an isolated scope.

```js
var app = angular.module("test",[]);

app.controller("myCntrl",function($scope){
    $scope.text = "Im in controller Scope";
});
app.directive("myDirective", function(){
    return {
        restrict: "EA",
        scope: true,
        template: "<div>Where are you, directive ? {{text}}</div>"
    };
});
```

```css
h2 {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.directive {
    border: 5px solid #F5BF6E;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test">
    
    <div ng-controller="myCntrl">
        <h2 ng-click="reverseName()">Where are you ? {{text}}</h2>
        <div my-directive class='directive'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can check this link for more details : [Directive Scopes](https://www.undefinednull.com/2014/02/11/mastering-the-scope-of-a-directive-in-angularjs/)

Comment: If you read my answer, it would help you. If you inherit the scope, you could access the parent scope, in that case, it's your controller's scope.

Comment: @ILIAS, is that what you were looking for ? Accessing controller's scope from directive....